# Office 2007 cannot find dll

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

When repairing office 2007 it comes up with a cannot find MSVCR80.dll message. I have extracted office2007.exe and the file is not in there.

Comment: Make sure the .exe your running is in the same folder as the .dll

Answer (score 0):

Search for same file from your hard drive C and copy and replace this same file from this location `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_0de06acd`  to the installation destination in folder `\office.en-us`.

To do this you might copy entire installation CD to a folder in your drive C. And run your installation from there...runs easily...QED

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **Microsoft Visual C++ 2005** from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347) (download the one for your system, or you can download all 3 and run them all until 1 installs), then restart the computer, and try the Office 2007 install again.